# A list of smartcards which support pkcs#11

Tags: smartcard, pkcs#11

I want to know is there exists a comprehensive list of smart cards that support pkcs#11 (or other standards like pkcs#15)?

I need a list like [Rousseau](http://ludovic.rousseau.free.fr/softwares/pcsc-tools/smartcard_list.txt)'s list.

Comment: Voted to close because it is not a real programming question, and the answer - if any - can & will only be a snapshot in time anyway. I'm afraid you will have to do such research yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for PKCS#11, you are probably looking for a cryptographic smart card. And if you are talking about cryptographic smart cards then I'm certain that 99% of smart card vendors do provide a PKCS#11 module for their cards. The functionality and availability of the  module can vary, of course.